# What is the best practice in vim8 for wrapping with indentation aka breakindent

Tags: vimrc, indentation, wrapping

To have proper paragraph wrapping with indentation in vim (after vim7.4) we could use this:

```
" Wrap the text with identation isntead of the old way 
set breakindent
set showbreak=\ \\_
```

Since [vim8](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/version8.txt) has introduced new features about break-indent I want to know if there would be a better practice?

*p.s. the option name is the same and this "new vim 8.0 features" might not be that new!*.

### Edit (Provide an example for proper indentation):

```
here is a list in markdown and normal vim act like this:
    * first item
    * second item blah blah blah blah  blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    * third time
```

and here is the proper way which is famously called "**wrapping with indentation**":

```
here is the base line:
    * first item
    * second item blah blah blah blah  blah blah blah blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah 
    * third time
```

Comment: "proper paragraph wrapping" only means something in your head. Describe what you want to achieve if you want meaningful help.

Comment: Have you eventually figured it out? I'm still looking for it and Googling about it every week.

Comment: I'm currently use `set breakindent` and `set showbreak=\ \\_` which works for all versions of vim and there is nothing specific about vim8!

Answer (score 1):

Starting from [vim 8.2.3198](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/f674b358fc18cf1641a066cc5de73da69e651024) there is `set briopt+=list:-1` that does what you want. It relies on `formatlistpat` to detect proper list indentation:

[image]

[image]